# How do I find the PID of the last open file in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

How to know the PID  of the last open file (process) using the command line?

Comment: I am assuming you don't mean the last time GNOME Terminal was opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PID of the last process started from the terminal can be found in the ! 
variable:

```
gedit &
echo $!
```