# Get Parent ID of last process executed in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

back to this [How do I find the PID of the last open file in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611661/how-do-i-find-the-pid-of-the-last-open-file-in-terminal)

I want to know the PPID (parent id of the process) of the last executed process.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't that just the Terminal's inner `bash` instance PID, i.e. e.g. `echo $$`?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153976/how-do-i-get-the-parent-process-id-of-a-given-child-process?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

In the same terminal, run the following command:

```
ps -p $! -o ppid=
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is ambiguous: are you asking for how to get the PPID of the last process executed *in* a Terminal or are you asking for how to get the PPID of the last process executed *doing so via* the Terminal?

If the first one, either I'm missing something or the PPID of the last process executed in the current Terminal's current inner `bash` instance is the current Terminal's current inner `bash` instance PID, which is always stored in `$`:

```
echo $$
```

If the second one you can run:

```
ps -e --sort -start_time -o ppid | head -5 | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal run this command:

```
<your_command> &
awk '{print $4}' "/proc/$\!/stat"
```

e.g.

```
$ gedit &                            
[1] 12130
$ awk '{print $4}' "/proc/$\!/stat"
11099
$ ps xa | grep 11099
11099 pts/0    Ss     0:01 /usr/bin/zsh
```